# react-native-router-flux -- adding back button and menu list

Tags: navbar, react-native-router-flux

In react-native-router-flux i wanna to add left, right and title, left button to go back to previous scene and right button for menu and title. how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example to start with:

https://marconijr.com/post/react-native-and-redux/